# Checking internet connectivity during startup iphone application

Tags: iphone

In my application i am using XML file from server.

So during start up of application i want to check internet connectivity.

If internet connectivity is not there then i want to show screen which tells user to exit .

How can i implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the "Reachability" files from the [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324) project and start it up like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
[internetReachable startNotifier];

hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"yourwebsite.com"] retain];
[hostReachable startNotifier];
```

Then check for internet connection as below. It is very convenient, as you can always check the connection on the fly when you need it.

```
if ([internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus]==NotReachable ||
    [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus]==NotReachable) {
    // react appropriately
}
```

Don't worry about this slowing you down - it is asynchronous. You can react to the Internet being up or down after making sure the UI does what the user expects.

Comment: Yes, you can put it into the app delegate and do the actual checking from the view controller class that should react to the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Um, you actually should not do this during startup, because it can make things very slow.

Right after startup you could use SCNetworkReachability.

Comment: CAn u expalin it a bit please. how can i use SCNetworkReachability

Answer (score 0):

It's a phone, with lots of radio power save modes, which can take a while (a variable amount of time) to turn on and (re)connect.  Just try to download your  XML asynchronously, and let the user decide if the connection is taking too long.

Otherwise you will risk telling the user to exit just after you've wasted radio power and the connection comes live again.

Comment: No, you can't rely on the user. The watchdog timer may kill you if you take too long to start.

Comment: @David : If you download asynchronously (set some delegates and return to the main run loop), the watchdog won't kill you.  It's Apple's own recommendation (WWDC 2009 session video IIRC).